# GCC warning for uninitialized data seems opposite of what the standard says

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization, compiler-warnings, member-initialization

Detailed code is given below, but basically: I have a class with some uninitialized data (not set in the ctor). When copying an instance of this class under certain circumstances, GCC gives no warning, even though it is reading uninitialized data to do so. Then, when wrapping the data in `union`, GCC *does* warn, but as far as I understand it, this is the one case where the standard *does* make a carve-out defining the behavior. So it seems like it should *not* warn in that second case.

In other words, the GCC behavior seems exactly the opposite of what it should be.

*Aside:* I realize that this is dealing with undefined behavior, so the compiler doesn't owe me anything, but given that GCC has specific warnings for this scenario, it seems strange that they are in opposition to (my interpretation of) the standard.

Please help me understand the issues at play.

Here is a godbolt live link demonstrating the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/Kdaa8M8qa

Note the use of `-Wuninitialized`.

### 1. Simple non-union case

```
struct MyObj {
    MyObj()
        // leave data uninitialized
        //: val(123), fval(9.5f)
    {}

    // Note: compiler-provided copy constructor
    
    //union {
        int val;
        float fval;
    //};
};
```

Here, when we put this object in a containing object, and make a copy of an instance of that container, we get *no* warning from GCC, even though `MyObj::val` and `fval` are clearly not initialized, and copying them is thus clearly UB. I would expect `-Wuninitialized` to catch this obvious issue.

See the use of the `Container` wrapper class, at the godbolt link given above.

### 2. Union case

[same code, but with the union being used](https://godbolt.org/z/na1oGooqq)

```
struct MyObj {

    // ...
    // same as above
    // ...
    
    union {
        int val;
        float fval;
    };
};
```

Here, we have the same as above, but wrap the members in a union.
From my understanding of the standard, unions get special treatment, and they have their "[object representation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy#ctor-15)" copied (much like `memcpy` would do). So, we are allowed to copy uninitialized values in this way, even if they have trap representations, etc.

However, confusingly, with this change, now GCC *does* issue a warning.

So, I want to know: **Is GCC's behavior correct in both cases, and my understanding is wrong? If so, please explain why, in detail.**

Comment: Almost all warnings have false negatives, meaning that there is almost always some code that should have been warned about that is missed. The lack of a warning doesn't guarantee absence of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't saying the copy assignment is the uninitialized use.

For example, this doesn't have the warning:

```cpp
cont = Container{ 10, {} };
cont.o.val = 2;  // <-- This is the added line
printf("Internal undefined val: %d (0x%x)\n", cont.o.val, cont.o.val);
```

The warning is supposed to say `<anonymous>` (the temporary materialized from `Container{ 10, {} }`) is being read from when it is not initialized *in the line with `printf`*.

Though the error should say something like `<temporary>.Container::o.MyObj::<anonymous>.MyObj::<unnamed union>::val` and point to the `printf` line, instead of to the line the temporary was created (maybe it should have both locations?)

It does tell you about the correct line if you use a constructor instead of assigning:

```cpp
Container cont = Container{ 10, {} };
// cont.o.val = 2;
printf("Internal undefined val: %d (0x%x)\n", cont.o.val, cont.o.val);
```

```cpp
<source>:50:11: warning: 'cont.Container::o.MyObj::<anonymous>.MyObj::<unnamed union>::val' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("Internal undefined val: %d (0x%x)\n", cont.o.val, cont.o.val);
     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: If I understand you, you're saying: (1) you believe the warnings are referring to the wrong lines (some GCC weakness, here), and (2) the only UB worth warning about here is in the `printf` statements, not from any copies. Do I have that right? It seems to me that copying from uninitialized data definitely *is* UB though, and thus worth warning about. Also, nothing in this answer addresses the difference in behavior w/regard to `union`, I take it?

Comment: @jwd Yes, the `union` makes it not UB. But GCC doesn't actually warn either way (`union` or not) for the copy, this warning just isn't shown for copy constructors / copy assign (whether that be intended because this is an extremely common pattern or it just hasn't been implemented)

Comment: In the second version of code in the question (using the union), if you remove all print statements from the program, the warning is still given — on assignment/copy. So, surely it can't be just the print statement that is generating the warning?